# Script para Execute em Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, funções

Estou realizando uma conversão em alguns objetos do bd onde estão com um nome fixo da base de dados.

Exemplo:

```
select * from banco.dbo.tabela ...
```

No caso, estamos trocando esse `banco` fixo, por uma variável que contem o nome em cada base. Nas procedures realizamos a conversão das sentenças em Scripts, concatenando a variável.

Exemplo:

```
 select * from '+@banco+'.dbo.tabela..
```

E executando com `sp_executesql`.

O problema é que em Function's não consigo executar esse comando. Poderiam me auxiliar com uma possível solução ao caso.

Ex:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mat.Retorna   
(        
    @valor INT         
   ,@valor2  INT      
   ,@valor3 INT             
) RETURNS INT    
AS    
BEGIN      

  DECLARE @valor4 INT    

  SELECT @valor4 = E001.coddot         
    FROM BANCO.dbo.tabela1 tb1      
    JOIN BANCO.dbo.tabela2 tb2 ON tb2.campo = tb1.campo         
    JOIN BANCO.dbo.tabela3 tb3  ON tb2.campo = tb3.campo          
    JOIN BANCO.dbo.tabela4 tb4  ON tb4.campo = tb3.campo      
                                   AND tb4.campo = @valor3      
   WHERE tb2.campo    < 50000        
     AND tb3.campo IS NULL        
     AND tb3.campo = @valor2      
     AND tb3.campo    = @valor      

  RETURN @valor4;    

END
```

Comment: Que tal excluir totalmente o prefixo do banco e utilizar um [`USE database;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188366.aspx) antes de executar as procedures?

Comment: Mas é que no caso são bases distintas, onde realizamos Join para verificações ou busca de informações.

Comment: E se somente a chamada da procedure você colocar o nome do banco? Exemplo: `Use bancoA;` `Call BancoB.dbo.procedure`

Comment: Não estou executando uma Procedure. Estou dando manutenção em uma Function. Na function existe um Select que retorna uma valor, porém, no select existe o join com as devidas tabelas com o Banco fixo. Queria poder alterar esse banco Fixo.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo. Onde o BANCO não pode ser um noma fixo, mas sim dinamico. Possuo uma function que retorna o nome da base local, onde posso atribuir a uma variável.

Comment: Você pode criar uma procedure que faça a consulta dinâmica e insira os resultados em uma tabela específica, e usar a função para selecionar a partir desta tabela (dá uma olhada [nesta pergunta do Ask SQL Server Central](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/44632/execute-dynamic-sql-from-within-a-function.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Em SQL Server não é possível executar stored procedures dentro de Functions, mas você poderá adicionar condições para executar instruções SELECT diferentes para cada banco de dados.

Segue um script T-SQL para você adaptar à sua necessidade:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Retorna
(
    @valor      INT
   ,@valor2     INT
   ,@valor3     INT
) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @valor4 INT

    IF @VALOR = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @valor4 =  1
    END

    IF @VALOR = 2
    BEGIN
        SET @valor4 =  2
    END

  RETURN @valor4;    

END
GO

SELECT dbo.Retorna(1, 2, 3)
GO
```

Para maiores informações veja:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191320.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186755(v=sql.110).aspx